# WMS source, selecting and printing region on multiple pages

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, wms, printing

I am new with GIS software.

I've imported topographic WMS source which shows whole country in ArcGis 10.2.2 and QGIS.

I want to select one specific region and print it in narrow scale (say, 1:15 000) on multiple pages (which would be something like 30 pages).

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is quite easily accomplished in ArcGIS for Desktop using these steps:

1. Create an index feature class (or shapefile) that represents the 30 pages that you want to print using [Create Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000).
2. Open ArcMap and use Add Data to add your WMS Server.
3. Use the [Data Driven Pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003n000000) toolbar to setup using the index you just created.
4. Export your maps to PDF (or the format of your choice) and print from them.

Comment: Thanks for replying quickly. I've thought about something even more foolproof since this is pretty much "hit and miss" for me: selecting that region and exporting it as huge image and letting printer splitting to some third party app. How is that doable?

Comment: It's not something that I would investigate but perhaps someone else will suggest an answer along those lines.

Comment: I guess I'm giving up. Learning curve is insanely steep with complex and not user friendly resources. Best I've managed to do in short time is to create that fishnet, link the ID's and actually go back/forward with buttons for that 30 pages on screen. However, everything I've managed to print is either 30 rectangles on one paper with no map background or one paper with whole map. I am selecting your answer to add to your reputation but honestly I'm uninstalling this. Thanks for help.